# Google App Engine loosing state of a JSP bean in session scope

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, session

I have the following JSP to test the problem

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<jsp:useBean id="testBean" class="java.util.ArrayList" scope="session"/>

<%
    testBean.add(System.currentTimeMillis());

    for(Object o : testBean){
%>

<%=o.toString()%><br>

<%}%>
```

If working correctly, it should print a list of last page reload millis. It does work on a dev server but not on a real GAE deployment. i.e.:

```
1396278093202
1396336675208
1396337414384 // <- Changes on each page refresh!?!?
```

On GAE is looses the state after 1-3 reloads and the list stops growing so only the last element changes its value on reload. The bean also survives an application update sometimes so i guess it could be a memcache problem.

This problem occurs only with `scope="session"`. There is no problem with `scope="application"`.

**Is this a known behavior and is there any workaround or ideas?**

*I'm using gae 1.9.1, session are enabled.*

**Update:**

session attribute handling seems to be completely broken:

```
<%
java.util.ArrayList testBean2= (ArrayList) session.getAttribute("testBean2");
if(testBean2==null){
    testBean2= new java.util.ArrayList();
    session.setAttribute("testBean2",testBean2);
}
testBean2.add(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
%>
```

The attribute loses its state after the second refresh.. so the size of the list is always 1 when it is retrieved from the session.

**Update 2**

I've found a workaround by myself. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAE does not persist the session on each request and tries to do this only on modification, but also fails to detect changes on session attributes if the attributes are mutable since it does not perform a deep object scan.

What GEA does is to trigger the session persistence on `setAttribute` call.

The solution is to **call `session.setAttribute` on each request**!

In my case the workaround is

```
<% session.setAttribute("stupidGaeWorkaround", System.currentTimeMillis());%>
```

Comment: Dude, you deserve a cookie!

Answer (score 1):

A nicer "workaround" is to override **equals** and **hashCode** in the object you are trying to store in the session.

I was experiencing the same issue with sessions, if I modified a *User* object in the session (which is the only one in my app) GAE would not persist the session, so I tried your workaround and it worked.
Finally I tested removing your workaround and implementing **equals** and **hashcode** in the *User* class and it also worked.

The appengine SDK version I am using is 1.9.17